# jqplot time axis does not displayin right

Tags: jquery, time, graph, line, jqplot

I have a jqplot line grapth

```
    $.jqplot('chartdiv1',  <?=$dataset?>,
            {
                title: 'GRAPT TITLE',
                axes: {
                    xaxis:{
                        label:"x axis",
                        renderer:$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
                        tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer ,
                        tickOptions:{formatString:'%d.%m.%y %H:%M:%S', angle: -30}
                    },
                    yaxis:{
                        label:"y axis",
                        labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer
                    }
                },
                highlighter: {
                    show: true,
                    sizeAdjust: 7.5
                },
                cursor:{
                    show: true,
                    zoom:true,
                    showTooltip:false
                }
            });
```

it displays like that

[image]

why it is not scalint properly on x axis?
values differ by 1 minute

Answer (score 1):

Add a min value to you axis :

```
axes: {
 xaxis: {
  label: "x axis",
  renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
  tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
  tickOptions:{formatString:'%d.%m.%y %H:%M:%S', angle: -30},
  min: '2013-02-05 10:50',
  max: '2013-02-05 12:15',
  tickInterval: '1 hour', //only if you want to draw a tick each hour.
  autoscale: false        //only if you want to draw a tick each hour. 
 } 
}
```

**Edit**

When you zoom in it's a "normal" behaviour to adapt xaxis bounds to data to be plotted. 
If -when you zoom out- your plot is getting the same behaviour as the beginning (empty mid-left), you can disable native zoom reset thanks to

```
cursor:{
   clickReset: false, 
   dblClickReset: false
}
```

And adding a new double click event handler after having drawn your plot :

```
$("#chartdiv1").dblclick(function(){resetZoomOnPlot(myplot);});
function resetZoomOnPlot(targetPlot){
  target.resetZoom();
  target.axes.xaxis.min = '2013-02-25 10:50';
  target.axes.xaxis.max = '2013-02-25 12:15';
  target.axes.xaxis._tickInterval = '1 hour';
  target.replot();    
}
```

Where myplot is a variable containing your plot : `var myplot = $.jqplot('chartdiv1', <?=$dataset?>, options);`. And options is a variable containing your jqplot options : `var options = {title: 'Graph title', axes: {...}...};`

Comment: well this helps, but it resets when i want to zoom in

Comment: Please give a look at the edited part of my previous answer. I think the zoom in behaviour is "normal", I've given you a way to correct the zoom out behaviour.